# Move an image to the corner with HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am currently designing a coming soon page and I want to push the voter hand all the way to the edge of the screen, I want parts of the sleeve cut off to achieve this. What would I need to change within the css/html code?

CSS Code:
`.container { position: relative; }  .top-left-image { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; object-fit: cover; z-index: 9999; }`

HTML Code:
`<div class="container">  <img src="Voter.png" alt="Voter holding a Ballot" class="top-left-image">  </div>`

[Current Coming Soon Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mlvX.png)

I've tried changing the z-index and position with no luck.

Comment: Try making left a negative value. left: -200px;

Comment: If your image is responsive (which should be - if it's not) move it to the negative left the needed amount of `%` like `left: -18%;` or you can also use responsive units like `vw` `vh` `vmin` `vmax` etc...

Answer (score 0):

With fixed position you can use a *negative* `left` value (like `left: -50px` - adjust as needed) to partly move the image out of the screen, i.e. to move it to the left.

If necessary (i.e. if the container doesn't start at the left edge of the window), also use `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `.container` element to hide the part that goes out of the container.

Same would apply to the `top` value when you want to move it up – just use a negative value.